# Ruby Airbone array testing is not working as expected

Tags: ruby, testing, airborne

I have the json below

```
{
    "menu": {
        "sections": [
            {
                "type": 4,
                "frames": [
                    {
                        "itens": []
                    }
                ],
                "order": 0
            },
            {
                "type": 4,
                "frames": [
                    {
                        "itens": [
                            {
                                "id": "1719016",
                                "type": 0,
                                "free": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "order": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and the test below that may check if all json itens in array `itens` has an ID property:

```
expect_json_keys('menu.sections.0.frames.*.itens.*', :id)
```

The problem is that this test runs fine. But should fail.

My test only fail when I change my expectations to that:

```
expect_json_keys('menu.sections.0.frames.*.itens.0', :id)
```

Why this test is succesful instead of fail when using `itens.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and tried to debug a bit.

I see this airborne gem for the first time (so take the following with a grain of salt), but I think the problem hides in the airborne implementation itself, here, to be more precise:  https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne/blob/master/lib/airborne/path_matcher.rb#L82

This line is intended to run expectation block ([this one](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne/blob/master/lib/airborne/request_expectations.rb#L25) in this particular case) for each item matching the wildcarded segment, but for an empty array it simply does nothing. No expectations run - no failures.

So it's not something wrong in your tests code, it's about the gem itself.
As a kind of workaround, you could try smth. like the following:

```
expect_json_types('menu.sections.0.frames.*.itens', :array_of_objects) # <= add this
expect_json_keys('menu.sections.0.frames.*.itens.*', :id)
```

e.g. testing the type of the value before testing the value itself - in this case it fails with `Expected array_of_objects got Array instead`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @konstantin-strukov. This solution works fine for this test case.

But in some test cases I still have to write some extra code.

The expectation you´ve writen fails for this json http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c827f26310000e8421d1e83. OK, I have a test case where it should really fail. I´ll use your solution in a lot of use cases. Thank you again.

But I have some test cases that shouldn´t fail if I have at least one filled `itens` property (http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c827f26310000e8421d1e83). `expect_json_keys('menu.sections.0.frames.*.itens.?', :id)` should be sufficient but it doesn´t because it works using `itens.*` or `itens.?`. I´ve tried to fit your solution in these test cases but it didn´t work as expected.